# Help identify funny Alfred Hitchcock homage

Tags: identify-this-movie, alfred-hitchcock

I saw this short film on American television some time in the late '70s or early '80s.  It pretended to be a low-budget homage to Alfred Hitchcock, with scenes and techniques based on Hitchcock's, only much more gratuitous and heavy-handed.  It had a voice-over/commentary that was supposedly the nerdy, overly enthusiastic student director explaining each scene to Hitchcock himself, with Hitchcock responding in a deadpan, unimpressed manner.  (I don't think it was really him, but it sounded like him.)

- There was a shower scene similar to the one in Psycho.  In the
  voice over, Hitchcock asks where the bathroom is, and the director
  starts to go into detail about where they filmed the scene.  Hitchcock interrupts
  him with "No, no.  WHERE is the BATHROOM?"
- There is a scene where someone is trying to hide among the spectators at a
  tennis match.  As the hand-held camera slowly approaches the stands, every head is turning back and forth in time with the sound of the ball being hit, except for the one guy in the center of the frame, who is staring straight ahead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is a short from 1973 called Norman Nurdelpick's Suspension: A Tribute to Alfred Hitchcock. I can't seem to find a clip of it anywhere. However, the Academy of Motion Picture Arts and Science (e.g.  the Oscars, The Academy Awards, etc) started a Student Academy Awards in 1973. A full list of winners can be found [here](http://www.oscars.org/awards/saa/winners/winners.pdf) and Norman Nurdelpick's Suspension: A Tribute to Alfred Hitchcock won the Special Jury (Dramatic) prize that year. The synopsis of the film as stated on that list of winners is "A dual-edged parody, the film satirizes Hitchcock's most famous scenes while also poking fun at a young auteur's slavish homage to the master" which sounds to me like what you are looking for.

Comment: This [1974 article](http://www.people.com/people/archive/article/0,,20064540,00.html) from *People* magazine includes a few additional details.

Comment: That's probably it!  I see on IMDB the film does show a voice credit for Michael Laskin as Alfred Hitchcock.  Too bad there are no clips online.  If there are no better prospects in the next few days I'll mark this as the accepted answer.